# Proportion Frequency Table with multiple Binary Data

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

First question I post here, I hope I'm not breaking too many policies.

I am trying to get a relative frequency table of several binary variables grouped by one or two other 
categorical variables.

```
country<-c('germany','germany','germany','USA','USA','USA','USA','germany','germany','USA')
sex<-c('female','male','male','female','female','female','male','female','female','female')
binary1<-c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
binary2<-c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)
binary3<-c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
df<-cbind(country,sex,binary1,binary2,binary3)
```

I would like to have something like this output:

```
Germany
  Female                                Male
    variable       0          1           variable       0          1 
    binary1      66.7%      33.3%         binary1      50.0%       50.0%    
    binary2      66.7%      33.3%         binary2      50.0%       50.0%
    binary3      100%        0%           binary3      0%         100%   

USA
  Female                                Male
    variable       0          1           variable       0          1 
    binary1      25%         75%          binary1       100%        0%    
    binary2      0%          100%         binary2       100%        0%
    binary3      25%         75%          binary3       100%        0%
```

It should be mentioned that I have a load of binary variables, please keep that in mind. This is one of my main problems implementing this one.

Any advice or recommendations you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try the following base R code

```
dfout <- lapply(split(df,df$country), 
                function(v) lapply(split(v,v$sex),
                                   function(x) 100*data.frame(Var0 = 1-colMeans(x[-(1:2)]),Var1=colMeans(x[-(1:2)]))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
$germany
$germany$female
             Var0     Var1
binary1  66.66667 33.33333
binary2  66.66667 33.33333
binary3 100.00000  0.00000

$germany$male
        Var0 Var1
binary1   50   50
binary2   50   50
binary3    0  100


$USA
$USA$female
        Var0 Var1
binary1   25   75
binary2    0  100
binary3   25   75

$USA$male
        Var0 Var1
binary1  100    0
binary2  100    0
binary3  100    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `data.table::cube` is a very good fit for this problem:

```
ans <- cube(melt(DT, id.vars=c("country", "sex")),
    .(c(0L, 1L), tabulate(value + 1L) / length(value)),
    c("country", "sex", "variable"))
ans[complete.cases(ans)]
```

output:

```
    country    sex variable V1        V2
 1: germany female  binary1  0 0.6666667
 2: germany female  binary1  1 0.3333333
 3: germany   male  binary1  0 0.5000000
 4: germany   male  binary1  1 0.5000000
 5:     USA female  binary1  0 0.2500000
 6:     USA female  binary1  1 0.7500000
 7:     USA   male  binary1  0 1.0000000
 8:     USA   male  binary1  1 1.0000000
 9: germany female  binary2  0 0.6666667
10: germany female  binary2  1 0.3333333
11: germany   male  binary2  0 0.5000000
12: germany   male  binary2  1 0.5000000
13:     USA female  binary2  0 0.0000000
14:     USA female  binary2  1 1.0000000
15:     USA   male  binary2  0 1.0000000
16:     USA   male  binary2  1 1.0000000
17: germany female  binary3  0 1.0000000
18: germany female  binary3  1 1.0000000
19: germany   male  binary3  0 0.0000000
20: germany   male  binary3  1 1.0000000
21:     USA female  binary3  0 0.2500000
22:     USA female  binary3  1 0.7500000
23:     USA   male  binary3  0 1.0000000
24:     USA   male  binary3  1 1.0000000
    country    sex variable V1        V2
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
country <- c('germany','germany','germany','USA','USA','USA','USA','germany','germany','USA')
sex<-c('female','male','male','female','female','female','male','female','female','female')
binary1 <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
binary2 <- c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)
binary3 <- c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
DT <- data.table(country,sex,binary1,binary2,binary3)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! 
This is only working with binary data (0,1) right? Is there a possibility to also use this cube function to work with categorical data? I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you post some samples of categorical variables? I can test tabulate with it

Comment: @Marius The function I wrote below will work with any number of levels of any of the variables

Answer (score 1):

Both of the two answers above get the job done but I wasted a bit of time on this one, probably self-isolation gone wild.  My first thought was use `janitor::tabyl` like `tabyl(df, sex, binary1, country) %>% adorn_percentages("row")` which gives you almost exactly what you want.  Unfortunately it only likes single bare variables and doesn't play well in a `purrr::map` chain.  So using basic `tidyverse` tools I wrote a custom function to create a tibble that will play nicely with `purrr` and then to teach myself more about `flextable` I used it to make the output nicer.  Please note your original data wasn't a dataframe so I changed that part.

The advantage of my solution **IMHO** is that it is very extensible and modifiable.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'flextable'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     compose
country <- c('germany','germany','germany','USA','USA','USA','USA','germany','germany','USA')
sex <- c('female','male','male','female','female','female','male','female','female','female')
binary1 <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
binary2 <- c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)
binary3 <- c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)

# make it a true dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(country,sex,binary1,binary2,binary3))

xtabs3 <- function(data,
                       x,
                       y,
                       z) {

  # internal helper function
  not_a_factor <- function(x){
    !is.factor(x)
  }

  # capture variable names
    xlab <- rlang::as_name(rlang::enquo(x))
    ylab <- rlang::as_name(rlang::enquo(y))
    zlab <- rlang::as_name(z)

  # create temp local dataframe 
    data <-
      dplyr::select(
        .data = data,
        x = {{ x }},
        y = {{ y }},
        z = {{ z }}
      )

  # calculate counts and percents 

  # x, y and z need to be a factor or ordered factor
  # also drop the unused levels of the factors and NAs
  data <- data %>%
    dplyr::mutate_if(.tbl = ., not_a_factor, as.factor) %>%
    dplyr::mutate_if(.tbl = ., is.factor, droplevels) %>%
    dplyr::filter_all(.tbl = ., all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
    dplyr::as_tibble(x = .)

  # convert the data into percentages; group by x, y, z
  # DO NOT Drop zeroes  
  df <-
    data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(.data = ., x, y, z, .drop = FALSE) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(.data = ., counts = n()) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(.data = ., perc = (counts / sum(counts)) * 100) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup(x = .) %>%
    rename(!!xlab := x, !!ylab := y, "level" := z)

    return(df)

}

# Make a list of all the binary variables we want to use
# best if it's a named list variables can be bare or quoted
fff <- alist(binary1 = binary1, binary2 = binary2, binary3 = binary3)
# fff <- alist(binary1, binary2, binary3)
# fff <- alist(binary1 = "binary1", binary2 = "binary2", binary3 = "binary3")

xxx <- purrr::map_dfr(.x = fff, ~ xtabs3(df, country, sex, .x), .id = "Which_binary")

xxx
#> # A tibble: 24 x 6
#>    Which_binary country sex    level counts  perc
#>    <chr>        <fct>   <fct>  <fct>  <int> <dbl>
#>  1 binary1      germany female 0          2  66.7
#>  2 binary1      germany female 1          1  33.3
#>  3 binary1      germany male   0          1  50  
#>  4 binary1      germany male   1          1  50  
#>  5 binary1      USA     female 0          1  25  
#>  6 binary1      USA     female 1          3  75  
#>  7 binary1      USA     male   0          1 100  
#>  8 binary1      USA     male   1          0   0  
#>  9 binary2      germany female 0          2  66.7
#> 10 binary2      germany female 1          1  33.3
#> # … with 14 more rows

myft <- flextable(xxx, col_keys = c("Which_binary", "country", "sex", "level", "perc"))
myft <- theme_vanilla(myft)
myft <- merge_v(myft, j = c("country", "sex", "Which_binary") )
myft <- autofit(myft)
myft <- colformat_num(x = myft, j = c("perc"), digits = 1, suffix = "%")
# reprex won't let me make an html table
plot(myft)
```

[image]

```r
# myft
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>